# Can't get my Jscrollpane working in my Jtextarea

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jscrollpane

I've looked around quite a lot on google and followed several examples however I can't seem to get my JScrollPane working on a textarea in a JPanel.

```
   import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.lang.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;

class main
{
    public static void main(String Args[])
    {
    frame f1 = new frame();
    }
}

class frame extends JFrame      
{

    JButton B = new JButton("B");   
    JButton button = new JButton("A");  
    JTextArea E = new JTextArea("some lines", 10, 20);
    JScrollPane scrollBar = new JScrollPane(E);
    JPanel grid = new JPanel ();        

    frame()
    {


    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(500,800);
    setTitle("Mobile Phone App");
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);        

    E.setLineWrap(true);
    E.setEditable(false);

     grid.add(button);
     button.addActionListener(new action());

    grid.add(B);
    B.addActionListener(new action());

    //grid.add(E);
    grid.getContentPane().add(scrollBar);
    add(grid);              



    setVisible(true);
    }
    class action implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            String V = E.getText();

            if(e.getSource() == button)
            {
                E.setText(V + "A is pressed");
            }
            if(e.getSource() == B)
            {
                E.setText(V + "B is pressed");
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Would be great if someone can see where I am going wrong. I added JscrollPane in which I added the text area "e" in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
E.setColumns(10);
E.setRows(5);
E.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(10,5)); // delete this
```

Don't hardcode a preferred size. The preferred size is overriding your attempt to set the rows/columns. So get rid of that line.

Note, you can also specify the row/columns when you create the text area:

```
JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(5, 10);
```

to provide a hint to the intial size of the text area. Now the text area can change in size as text is added or removed and the scrollbar will appear when needed.

Also follow standard java naming conventions. Variable names should NOT start with an upper case character.

Comment: Ok thanks for that bit of info. I followed what you said however now when the text gets to the end of the textbox...it makes the textbox larger rather then a scroll showing up

Answer (score 0):

Right I got it!

Basically I had to add it in differently...the way I was approaching it was wrong!

```
grid.add(scrollBar, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```